# I could not see the message I posted. Google+ API

Tags: php, google-plus

I have a question about message post through Google+ API.
I tried steps below but I could not see the message I posted.
What should I do to success posting?
Also if there are any demos or sample codes, please tell me.

Steps I tried:

1. Followed the instructions on the site below
   http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/
   executed examples/plus/simple.php 
   I can success until I aquire profile.
2. Added codes to examples/plus/simple.php
   code was from this site:
   https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert?hl=ja
   There were no errors or exceptions. Methods from $plus->moments->insert returned codes below,
   but I could not see the message on my google+ timeline.

---

```
array(5) {
  ["kind"]=>
  string(11) "plus#moment"
  ["type"]=>
  string(37) "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
  ["target"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["kind"]=>
    string(14) "plus#itemScope"
    ["url"]=>
    string(62) "https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing"
  }
  ["result"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["kind"]=>
    string(14) "plus#itemScope"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  string(63) "Eg0xMzg0MjUxOTM3MTYzGJnjm7jHtPWdKykIe5CARCjQCTICEBRCBxi6gpjDhBw"
}
array(5) {
  ["kind"]=>
  string(11) "plus#moment"
  ["type"]=>
  string(37) "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
  ["target"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["kind"]=>
    string(14) "plus#itemScope"
    ["id"]=>
    string(11) "target-id-1"
    ["description"]=>
    string(50) "A page that describes just how awesome Google+ is!"
    ["image"]=>
    string(66) "https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing.png"
    ["name"]=>
    string(20) "The Google+ Platform"
  }
  ["result"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["kind"]=>
    string(14) "plus#itemScope"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  string(75) "Eg0xMzg0MjUxOTM3NzExGJnjm7jHtPWdKzICEBRCBxi6gpjDhBxKEFuVHwoS2gtqh7B5zMyXBB0" 
}
```

Thank you.
Makoto Takahashi

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding a little bit how `moments.insert` works. This does **not** insert a message onto your timeline directly - there is no public API that allows you to do this without explicit user approval.

What `moments.insert` does is create an *app activity* which is stored as part of your user profile. People who are permitted to this app activity can see it as part of your profile, associated with your app, and you can see it there as well, but in order for it to appear on your timeline you must explicitly share it.

You can see your app activities by going to https://plus.google.com/apps and selecting your app. Others can see your app activities by going to your profile and selecting the appropriate app from the list of apps you've shared with them.